# Dividing Doubles in Kotlin returns NaN

Tags: kotlin, division

I was dividing two doubles in Kotlin and when I tried to divide by Zero, kotlin returns NaN instead of an Arithmetic Exception. Is that correct?
[Image dividing double returning NaN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwiis.png)

Comment: Yes, that’s what it does. ArithmaticExceptions are for integer types.

Comment: It's correct. There is a convention that dividing an integer by 0 throws an error and dividing a float by 0 (or an integer by 0.0) returns NaN.

Comment: Like most languages, Kotlin uses IEEE754 specification for floating-point arithmetic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#NaNs, also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken